# Retrieve data from mysql and update them accordingly

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to retrieve data from my MySQL database and display it as a table (I don't mind any style, but preferred as a table).  Then the data should display with a radio button or a normal button which update that specific row and changing a single column in that row to Active (Status making Active).

I have started it, but I still have issues with adding a radio button or a button. Then I thought of displaying the information in a table which inside a form. This form will have each radio buttons, when the person select that radio button and press submit. The data should be updated in the MySQL database.

Can someone guide me about this?  I'm a bit confused. I'm confused because I have to add a form and in that form I have to add a table and all this stuff should be in a php file.

Comment: what's wrong with just `<form><table>..</table></form>`? Also, I'd suggest to use checkbox instead of radio. Checkbox has a value parameter which can be useful to hold row's id

Answer (score 0):

on formpost.php page you can do something like this for handling the list array you received from the previous page:

```
<?
$list = $_POST['list'];

foreach ($list as $key => $list_php) 
{
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `stu_entry` WHERE `stu_entry`.`Student_No` = '$list_php' AND `stu_entry`.`Out_Time` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
$row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);


//whatever you want to do

}
?>
```

I forgot to tell you something in the previous post. In the form page, lets say you have 100 rows with 100 checkboxes. It would be nasty to manually check or uncheck all of them. As an alternative you could append a little script at the end of the page to handle the checking/ unchecking process for you:

```
<script>
function checkAll(field)
{
for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
    field[i].checked = true ;
}

function uncheckAll(field)
{
for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
    field[i].checked = false ;
}

function countChecks(form){
var t=0;
var c=form['list[]'];
for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){
c[i].checked?t++:null;
}
return t;
}

</script>

<input type="button" name="CheckAll" value="Check All"
onClick="checkAll(document.formpost['list[]'])">
<input type="button" name="UnCheckAll" value="Uncheck All"
onClick="uncheckAll(document.formpost['list[]'])">

<i>with selected: </i>

<select name="submit_mult" id="submit_mult">
    <option value="todo1">Action 1 </option>
    <option value="todo2">Action 2 </option>
    </select>
<input type="button" name="go" value="Go" onClick='if(countChecks(this.form)>0) {if(confirm("are you sure you want to \""+document.getElementById("submit_mult").options[document.getElementById("submit_mult").selectedIndex].text+" "+countChecks(this.form)+" items selected"+"\"")) {document.getElementById("referenceToSomeHiddenElement").value=document.getElementById("submit_mult").options[document.getElementById("submit_mult").selectedIndex].value;document.getElementById("formpost").submit();}} else alert("you have not selected any item!!")' >
```

Tell me if you need more help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I first specify a MySQL command which in return gives me an array. I use a while statement to do something to each item in the array. The array is populated with the field name and the field contents.

```
$mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($mysql))
{
  $output .= '<form>Row: ' . $array['fieldname'] . ' <input type="button" value="Update" /></form>';
}
```

This extracts all rows from the table and adds a form to the variable $output for every result. I'm unsure of how you want to update your database, so you will have to look into it. You can use GET and POST methods.

Answer (score -1):

Go ahead and try something like this. And tell me if that worked:

```
<p><b>your page name</b></p>
<form name="formpost" id="formpost" action="formpost.php" method="POST">
<table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#999999" width="800">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Sno.</b></td>
    <td><b>Field name1</b></td>
    <td><b>Field name2</b></td>
    <td><b>Field name3</b></td>
    <td><b>Field name4</b></td>
    <td><b>Field name5</b></td>
    <td><b>Field name6</b></td>
    <td><b>Field name7</b></td>
  </tr>

  <?
  $sorting="";
  if($orderby!="" && $direction!="")  $sorting=" ORDER BY $orderby $direction";    
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = 'something' $sorting";  
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  ?>
  <tr>
  <?
  $i=0;
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
  $i++;

  ?>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="list[<?echo $i?>]" id="list[]" value="<?echo $row['some_primary_field_id']?>"><?echo $i?></td>
  <td><?echo $row['Field1']?></td>
  <td><?echo $row['Field2']?></td>
  <td><?echo $row['Field3']?></td>    
  <td><?echo $row['Field4']?></td>
  <td><?echo $row['Field5']?></td>
  <td><?echo $row['Field6']?></td>
  <td><p align="center">

  <?  
  echo "<input title='button' name='change this row' value='Some Button' type='button' onClick=\"if(confirm('Press OK to change status to confirm')) {document.getElementById('someid').value='".$row['Field1']."';document.getElementById('formpost').submit();}\"/>";
  ?>
  </td>
  </tr>
<input type='hidden' name="hiddenlist[<?echo $i?>]" id="hiddenlist[]" value="<?echo "some boundry condition ".$row['Field2']?>">

<?
} //end of while
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: you can write addslashes() to sanitise data wherever need in the formpost.php. This will take care of SQL injection.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=337881. We can possibly use mysql_real_escape_string() to add support for character that ends in 0x5c.

Comment: @Col-Shrapnel what do you suggest for preventing SQL injection.